# API Facebook Marketing error: Unsupported get request. Object with ID XXXXXX does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

Upvote
1
Hi all,

I launched this request:

https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/ACCOUNT_ID/campaigns?fields=name&access_token=YYYYY

and I received the following error:

"Unsupported get request. Object with ID XXXXXX does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation".

The ACCOUNT_ID is the my account ID and the access token is the token that I receveid from this request:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXXX&client_secret=ZZZZZZ

My ads account is administrator and if I check in the authorizations of the app I found Standard Access for all the permissions, included ads_read that is the one I need to my scope that is simple to read the information of the campaigns.

Could anyone help me understand why the first request I wrote doesn't work?

Thank you,
Giuliana

Answer (score 0):

The ID should be in this format: `act_<ACCOUNT_ID>` (without the chevrons). Note the `act_` prefix.

Comment: Hi Riwen, thank you for your reply. Also with act_MYACCOUNT_ID I obtain the same message: "The object ID act_XXXXXX  does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation".  I don't have already campaigns, but I thing that is not the issue because I should obtain a empty response. Do you suggest other advice?

Comment: You may need to use a [System User access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/system-users/). Please see [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/system-users/install-apps-and-generate-tokens).